# Can a Linux OS be installed on a Windows 8.1 tablet and co-exist with Windows 8.1?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8.1

Something like what desktop machine called 'Dual-boot', so can linux os (e.g. [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) or [Mozillux](http://www.linuxinsider.com/story/78193.html)) can be installed in a Windows 8.1 tablet and co-exist with it and allow me to 'dual-boot' either one of the OS?

Comment: take a look at this special Fedora version for Baytrail tablets: https://www.happyassassin.net/fedlet-a-fedora-remix-for-bay-trail-tablets/

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done.

[Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-8-rt/general/dual-booting-ubuntu-windows-8-1-pipo-w2-t2926413) is post from XDA-Developers on how to setup a dual boot system with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 using a Pipo W2 tablet.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mcv0jtPesNU) is a video showing an Asus Transformer Book TX300 successfully dual booted with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10.

So it is possible. But the architecture of the device x86 or ARM will play an important factor. Both the devices I have mentioned are x86 based.

As for ARM based tablets, there are quite a few examples around the internet showing Ubuntu dual booted with Android. But I have not seen much about Windows 8.1 dual booted with Linux on an ARM based device.

Note: You will need a USB keyboard for selecting the OS in the boot screen if you manage to dual boot Windows with Linux on a tablet. Because the touchscreen won't be active until you boot into any one of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

There have been posts about [Microsoft banning dual-booting feature in their ARM devices](http://www.dailytech.com/Microsoft+Bans+LinuxAndroid+DualBooting+on+Windows+8+ARM+Devices/article23785.htm), so no, its not possible in **legal way**. But I'm pretty sure that there are workarounds which may help you, but in this case it would be license violation which may lead to problems in future (like repair and RMA). Those guides may also break your device, but you can easily find them in global search.

**EDIT**

For non ARM-based devices: [yes its possible](http://blog.davidelner.com/dual-booting-ubuntu-14-10-on-the-surface-pro-3/), but it still may be a violation of agreement.

Comment: The device in question is a Windows 8.1 tablet. It is not an ARM device,

Comment: Microsoft can't ban you putting whatever you want on a product you own - they can only lock their systems down to prevent it, and - in some places without good consumer protections - void warranties and not support it.  (Sorry I'm a pedant, but the subtle differences are important to me as by allowing the wrong words to be used we elevate their actions above what they are, and give people the wrong idea).   Importantly, I've yet to read a EULA (I do read them) which prevents you from putting on another OS - and if this were even the case, why would Microsoft not simply enforce Secure booting?

Comment: If you have device like Surface Pro you have to accept license they provide which clearly tells you how their device should be used (which includes type of OS as well). If we are talking about non-Microsoft devices/tablets situation is different. Idea is "We sell you a device and we provide you support as far as you don't do something strange with our device. Because if you do, we have to put more resources to find and fix the problem, which costs us more money and time". What I'm trying to say is that not ALL of manufacturers lock their products, but there are a lot of who actually does.

Comment: Also, I edited the answer so you got a link to one guide which describes step-by-step installation of Ubuntu on your "originally Windows-based" tablet. So I don't understand your further commenting an arguing about things which are not directly related to your question, "So can linux os (e.g. Ubuntu or Mozillux) can be installed in a Windows 8.1 tablet and co-exist with it and allow me to 'dual-boot' either one of the OS?". Information about violation of an agreement is just in case so you know what you are doing.